# convert string into 2 dimensional list with no imports

Tags: python, io

I need to convert a string representation into a 2 dimensional list.

I am trying to read inputs from a text file. All inputs follow a standard format where each line represents a different variable. When I read the following line from the input file using f.readline():

```
[[0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0], [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0]]
```

This line is read in as a string, but I need it converted to a 2 dimensional list. A constraint for this project is I cannot use any packages, only base python.

How do I do this?

Comment: I think a for loop with a couple of `split()` statements would do the job. You just need to remove the `[` and `]` every time.

Comment: like `(split("],")`?

Comment: Yes and since you are trying to create a 2D array, 1st split elements by a `],` then cycle through the elements, remove the `[` and `]` through `replace()` and then use split again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
text = "[[0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0], [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0]]"

output = []
for sublist in text.split('], '):
    sublist = sublist.replace('[',  '').replace(']', '')
    data = []
    for number in sublist.split(', '):
        data.append(int(number))
    output.append(data)
print(output)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
text = "[[0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0], [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0]]"

output = [[int(number) for number in sublist.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ')] for sublist in text.split('], ')]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

This short script should work:

```
string_lists = "[[0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0], [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0]]"

parsed_list = string_lists[1:-2].split("], ")  # remove last 2 brackets and then split into lists

for index, row in enumerate(parsed_list):
    parsed_list[index] = row[1:].split(", ")  # split sublists into individual elements
    parsed_list[index] = [int(num) for num in parsed_list[index]]  # cast each element to int
    
print(parsed_list)
```

Note that you don't have to create additional list like I did, you can just work on your starting string (just change "parsed_list" to "string_lists" everywhere in above script)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see some pattern firstly. We have:

`[` `[a1, a2, ..., ap1]`, `[b1, b2, ..., bp2]`, ..., `[xx1, xx2, ..., xxpn]` `]`.

we have to select some separator which will help us divide it into groups. I'd prob go for `], [` but you can choose even `],`

so we have to remove `[[` and `]]` from our string to have clear pattern.

```py
inp.strip('[]')
```

we split it into sublists

```py
inp.strip('[]').split('], [')
```

now every sublist in format:

`a1, a2, ..., ap1`

we split it on `,`  so we will get items.

```py
sublist.split(', ')
```

We summarize it and take as one list comprehension:

```py
list_from_string = [[int(item) for item in sublist.split(', ')] for sublist in inp.strip('[]').split('], [')]
```

Answer (score 1):

What a fun problem! Found this simple solution that iterates the string only once:

```py
output_list = list()  # Contains the output
inner_list = None  # Current "row"/"column"
current_value = ""  # Keep track of the current value

for char in list_as_text[1:-1]:
    if char == " ":
        # Ignore spaces
        continue
    elif char.isdigit():  # Add `or char == "."` to support float values
        # Found a digit, keep track of the current value
        current_value += char
    elif char == ",":
        # Found a comma, save the value in inner_list
        inner_list.append(int(current_value))  # Use `float(current_value)` to support float values
        # Start a new current_vale
        current_value = ""
    elif char == "[":
        # We start a new inner_list
        inner_list = list()
    elif char == "]":
        # We completed an inner_list
        output_list.append(inner_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step approach using `split()`, `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` methods of the `string` datatype:

```
row = '[[0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0], [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0]]'

listOfStrings = [s.rstrip(' ,]') for s in row.split('[')]
listOfStrings = [s for s in listOfStrings if len(s) > 0]
listOfLists = [[int(n.lstrip(' ')) for n in s.split(',')] for s in listOfStrings]
print(listOfLists)
```

Line 1 creates a string containing comma-separated values for each list in the original with some extra empty strings.

Line 2 eliminates the empty strings.

Line 3 creates a list of lists of numbers.